# Input function as a Combo Box VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a macro that will run then pause the macro and allow the user to input a value then continue running again. I know there is InputBox function available but I want the box to pop up to be a drop down list. I am not sure how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a userform and put a combobox on it. Use this userform instead of the msgbox.

Comment: Siddharth thank you for the response! would you mind showing me a example of what the code would look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Siddharth thank you for the response! would you mind showing me a example of what the code would look like –  fishing king 13 6 mins ago

Hope this gets you on the right track...

Add a Userform and add a Combobox to it. I am adding some basic data in the combo to show you how it works. Change as applicable

[image]

Your Userform will have a code something like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "option1"
        .AddItem "option2"
        .AddItem "option3"
        .AddItem "option4"
        .AddItem "option5"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then MsgBox "the user chose or typed " & ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Next amend your macro so that it looks like this

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Do Some Stuff
    '
    UserForm1.Show
    '
    '~~> Continue doing Some Stuff
    '
End Sub
```

**Followup from comments**

> One more question If the value of my drop down come from a named range. How do I define that? –  fishing king 13 3 mins ago

Use `.List` instead of `.AddItem`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Range("MyNamedRange"))
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! One more question If the value of my drop down come from a named range. How do I define that?

Comment: Siddharth Rout thank you very much for your help! I will try this process later today.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you face any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured that many will use public variable to get the value backfrom the userform, which is a simple, but not as efficient way of doing this (in my opinion).

This example should be, I hope, a bit better way of doing it.

First create your userform : (here named "UF_Combobox")

[Example of userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SwDi.png)

In the userform code, create a function that both displays/closes the userform and get the value back, through the function to the calling subroutine when doing so :

```
Option Explicit
Function Select_Value(ByVal Question As String, ByRef Values() As Variant, Optional ByVal Default_Index As Long = -1) As Long

Dim index As Long

'Fill the question
    Textbox.Value = Question

'Fill the combobox with values
    For index = LBound(Values, 1) To UBound(Values, 1)
    
        Combobox.AddItem Values(index)
    
    Next index

'Select the default value
    Combobox.ListIndex = Default_Index
    
'Display the question (= the userform)
    Me.Show '| Rest of function is suspended until "me.hide" is triggered
    
'Get the index value
    Select_Value = Combobox.ListIndex
    
'Close
    Unload Me
```

I use a textbox set to multiple lines instead of a label, which is better in the case you have a long question, it will put the questions on multiple lines (adapt size if needed) instead of cuting it after the edge of userform.

Put a subroutine that will trigger the "me.hide" fonction which will trigger the end of the previous function. The commandbutton triggers it.

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

And here is how you can use it in a common module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Choice()

'Variables
    Dim days() As Variant
    Dim chosen_day As String
    Dim index As Long
        
'List
    days = Array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday")

'Get the index value from the userform
    index = UF_ComboBox.Select_Value(Question:="Meeting day ?", Values:=days, Default_Index:=0)

'Treatment
    Select Case index
    
    Case -1
        chosen_day = "No day chosen !"
    
    Case Else
        chosen_day = days(index)
    
    End Select

    MsgBox chosen_day

End Sub
```

This is just a simple example but you can obviously add options and buttons as you want. A "necessary" boolean parameter in the "select_value" function might be a smart add so you can force the user to choose a value.